# how i can build HTML table which contain merged cells on the first column and 2 cells on the second column

Tags: html

I want to build this table in HTML :-

[image]

so how i can do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rowspan` property.
Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowspan` in that case, if it's horizontal merge you can use `colspan`

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-row-col-span-43ryx

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan